# Unity Works Slow On Fixed Resoultion Game Mode Display

Tags: unity

So I encountered a really weird behavior in the Unity editor where when I set my game mode display to some aspect ratio (e.g 18:9) everything works perfectly fine, but as soon as I switch it to fixed resolution (e.g 1080X2220) the editor getting extremely slow and in the game mode I get an extremely low FPS of around 2.

It took me a while to understand that that's where the slowness coming from, but I don't understand exactly how to fix it, never experienced anything like that.
Happened on two different computers, with high capabilities and good specs, which make me things that it might be something in the project settings(?)

Profile screenshots attached.

Any advice would be great,

Thanks in advance,
Omer

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the profiler show at these two different resolutions?

Comment: The profile screenshots are now attached. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you've shown us two sceenshots from the same run, at the same resolution and framerate (~200 fps). To be able to help you, we need to contrast this with the case where the game is running slow (the 2 fps case you described). Without seeing that profile result, we can only speculate about what is making it slow.